# how to loop over one axis of numpy array, returning inner arrays instead of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several arrays of data, collected into a single array. I want to loop over it, and do operations on each of the inner arrays. What would be the correct way to do this in Numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9)
a = a.reshape(3,3)
for val in np.nditer(a):
    print(val)
```

and this gives:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

But what I want is (something like):

```
array([0 1 2])
array([3 4 5])
array([6 7 8])
```

I have been looking at this page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html but so far have not found the answer. I also know I can do it with a plain for loop but I am assuming there is a more correct way. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: numpy is useful for vectorized operations. For what purpose are you trying to iterate over the rows of the ndarray? What operations do you want to perform?

Comment: Don't use `nditer`.  It isn't the 'correct way' to iterate on arrays, at least not in Python code.  You are encouraged to use it when writing C code, but not when writing Python code.  As you discovered its default behavior is to iterate on all elements, not on a specific dimension.

Comment: The linked page should be read all the way to the end.  The cython example is really the main point of this document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) but it depends on what your ultimate goal/output is. Here is a simple example showing this.

```
a

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x + 1, 0, a)

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use reshape it will return an array of lists not arrays.

If you would like to get each individual list you could just use

```
a = np.arange(9)
a = a.reshape(3,3)
for val in a:
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply loop over the array where you get individual rows in the for loop

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9)
a = a.reshape(3,3)

for val in a:
    print(val)

# [0 1 2]
# [3 4 5]
# [6 7 8]
```